# Help finding PWM IC with marking on device '63H51a'. Package of device is SOT23-6

Tags: integrated-circuit, pwm, identification

I am trying to do some reverse engineering on a 12V DC wall adapter where I found this 6 pin PWM IC marked 63H51a. I am unable to find any of its details on Google. So requesting if anyone could help me in finding the device name.

[image: photo of unknown IC on PCB]

Comment: Welcome, could you provide a closeup photo of the IC? Also a photo of the pcb would be helpful!

Comment: @HansmitmFlammenwerfer - Hi, In case you didn't get notified, FYI a photo has now been added by the OP.

Answer (score 1):

It's a [On-Bright OB2263MP](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/1811051522_OB-On-Bright-Elec-OB2263MP_C52977.pdf) PWM controller.

[image]

[image]

(Source: [lcsc.com](https://www.lcsc.com/product-detail/AC-DC-Controllers-Regulators_OB-On-Bright-Elec-OB2263MP_C52977.html))